# How to validate acm certificate created via terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create 3 certificates for 3 services named test,valid,jsc and using an exiting hosted zone.But terraform is failing in cert validation stating that certificate is in pending_validation state

```
variable "service-names" {
  type    = list(any)
  default = ["valid", "jsc", "test"]

}



resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  for_each = toset(var.service-names)
  domain_name       = "www.us.${each.value}.xxxxx.cloud"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  tags = {
    Name = "www.us.${each.value}.xxxxx.cloud"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}



data "aws_route53_zone" "ecomzoneinfo" {
  name         = "xxxxx.cloud"
  tags = {
     "Name" = "www.us.${each.value}.xxxxx.cloud"
   }
}

locals {
  dns-record-list = flatten([
    for svc in var.service-names : [
      for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.cert[svc].domain_validation_options : {
        name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
      service = svc
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "ecom-route" {
  for_each = { for idx,dns in local.dns-record-list : "${dns.service}" => dns }
  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = data.aws_route53_zone.ecomzoneinfo.zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "ecom" {
   for_each = toset(var.service-names)
   certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.cert[each.value].arn
   validation_record_fqdns = [aws_route53_record.ecom-route[each.value].fqdn]
 }
```

Getting Error stating as certificate is in pending validation and yes i'm able to the certs created by terraform aws_acm_certification resource are in pending status.Even i'm able to see the cname records are added under the zone xxxxx.cloud hosted zone.So i'm not sure what is wrong here

```
Error: Error describing created certificate: Expected certificate to be issued but was in state PENDING_VALIDATION
│ 
│   with aws_acm_certificate_validation.ecom["jsc"],
│   on main.tf line 449, in resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "ecom":
│  449:   resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "ecom" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: Error describing created certificate: Expected certificate to be issued but was in state PENDING_VALIDATION
│ 
│   with aws_acm_certificate_validation.ecom["test"],
│   on main.tf line 449, in resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "ecom":
│  449:   resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "ecom" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: Error describing created certificate: Expected certificate to be issued but was in state PENDING_VALIDATION
│ 
│   with aws_acm_certificate_validation.ecom["valid"],
│   on main.tf line 449, in resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "ecom":
│  449:   resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "ecom" {
```

Comment: If you do these steps manually, do they work? So the issue is only with TF?

Comment: I would start by going into the web console to verify the DNS records ACM wants you to create for verification, and then going into Route53 and verifying those are created. Your terraform code is hard to follow, so I would start by just verifying if the expected resources were created.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/acm_certificate_validation) provided.

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "certificate" {
  domain_name = "mydomain.com"
  subject_alternative_names = [
      "*.mydomain.com"
  ]
  validation_method = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "acm-records" {
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.certificate.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records = [
    each.value.record
  ]
  ttl     = 60
  type    = each.value.type
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.mydomain.zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "acm-validation" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.certificate.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.acm-records : record.fqdn]
}
```