# How to fix Certificate not found issue when creating ALb using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create aws application load balancer via terraform.I'm creating key ,ssk cert everything via TLS provider.But when terraform creating application load balancer it is not able to detect the certificate.But able to see the certificate exist in acm

```
Error: error creating ELBv2 Listener (arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:xxxxxxxx:loadbalancer/app/tf-lb-************6b77): CertificateNotFound: 
Certificate 'arn:aws:acm:ap-south-1:xxxxxxx4551:certificate/xxxxxxxx-401d-a077-xxxx1661' not found
│       status code: 400, request id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
│ 
│   with aws_lb_listener.ecom-alb-listener["xxxxx-443-HTTPS"],
│   on main.tf line 527, in resource "aws_lb_listener" "ecom-alb-listener":
│  527: resource "aws_lb_listener" "ecom-alb-listener" {
```

But it is exist in aws certificate manager

[image]

code:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  for_each = toset(var.service-names)
  private_key      = tls_private_key.ecom-key[each.value].private_key_pem
  certificate_body = tls_self_signed_cert.ecom-sscert[each.value].cert_pem
  tags = {
    Name = "www.us.${each.value}.xxxx.cloud"
   }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "ecom-alb-listener" {
  for_each = { for idx, svc in local.merged_applbport_svc : "${svc.service}-${svc.port}-${svc.protocol}" => svc }
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.application-lb[each.value.service].arn
  certificate_arn   = "${each.value.port == 443 ? aws_acm_certificate.cert[each.value.service].arn : null}"
  port              = each.value.port
  protocol          = each.value.protocol
  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.ecom-alb-tgp["${each.value.service}-${each.value.port}-${each.value.protocol}"].arn
    type             = "forward"
  }
}
```

for testing pupose ,I  created a loadbalancer manually and try to attach certificate.But getting no valid certficates

[image]

Is that expiry 0 days is causing this?
[image]

Even manually imported a certificate as below and hardcoded the certificate arn in aws_alb_listener.But still getting certificate not found.Is it anything related to aws permission issue?But used same cred of importing certificate for terraform also

[image]

```
Error: error creating ELBv2 Listener (arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:1xxxxxxxxxx1:loadbalancer/app/tf-lb-20210515140007xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx71): CertificateNotFound: Certificate 'arn:aws:acm:ap-south-1:1147xxxxxxxx:certificate/e9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx11' not found
│       status code: 400, request id: 61xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8b
│ 
│   with aws_lb_listener.ecom-alb-listener["valid-443-HTTPS"],
│   on main.tf line 530, in resource "aws_lb_listener" "ecom-alb-listener":
│  530: resource "aws_lb_listener" "ecom-alb-listener" {
```

Comment: Can you show the code producing the error? Also ACM is region specific, so your ALB could be in different region?

Comment: @Marcin added the code.Also alb is also in same region as ap-south-1

Comment: If you try to add the cert manually using console, it all works? So the problem is only with TF?

Comment: @Marcin yes i'm unable to add that certificate manually also

Comment: Could be in the wrong format. ACM supports more versions and types of certs than ALB. Have you tried with ACM generated cert, rather then using the imported one?

Answer (score 0):

Your *[previous question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67508262/6085193) indicates your certificate is not validated*... you cannot proceed to this step without fixing that.

[image]

> Only *VALIDATED certificates can be attached* as ACM certificate to a load balancer or other AWS resource such as Cloudfront

- To prove this try changing your data source to find only `ISSUED` certificates

You will notice it will notice the error now moves further down in the data source if there are no validated certificates that match your pattern:

```
data "aws_acm_certificate" "test_cert" {
  domain   = "*.somedomain.com"
  statuses = ["ISSUED"]  
}
```

---

**Update to comment below:**

Yes, *Last I used it*, I `had to validate my certs before` we could use it as shown by their AWS dev. guide.

[image: AWS help requires validation]

Comment: If I create certs using TLS provider still we need to validate?from my understanding it is similar to import cert,so validation method is none for us.my prev question I didn't used TLS to create certs

Comment: @jp in my env. yes. see the picture I attached, and if this is helping please upvote/mark as answer.

Comment: If that is the case,what you will provide for validation_record_fqdns = [aws_route53_record.ecom-route[each.value].fqdn] in aws_acm_certificate_validation resource.Do we need to create route53 record?If so why we need that for validation_method = none which is default for import certs?